# How do I change the background color of a DIV with a function using a button with 'IF' conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My question might be a bit vague but here's what I have right now. [Here's the fiddle I did](http://jsfiddle.net/vo0d9ubj/)

I need the **More** button to change background color to orange every time the **orange background** *button* is clicked and only if the **More** div is still at the bottom of the screen (*The MORE button slides up when it's clicked*)

[image: this is how]

And some snippet of my code:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.chatbox').hide();
    $('#btn-chat').click(function() {
        $("#blk-collaboration .chatbox").slideToggle("slow",function(){
        $("#blk-collaboration #toggle").css("background","transparent");
    });
      $(this)//this is a button DOM element. wrapping in jQuery object.
      .toggleClass('wide'); // removing wide class so button became smaller.
    });
});

function changeColor(color) {
document.getElementById("circle").style.backgroundColor = color;
}

document.getElementById("online").onclick = function() { changeColor("#92bf1e"); }
document.getElementById("offline").onclick = function() { changeColor("#747474"); } 
document.getElementById("upcoming").onclick = function() { changeOrange("#f4b066"); } 



</script>
```

Here are the buttons...

```
<input id="online" type="button" value="Online" />
<input id="offline" type="button" value="Offline" />
<input id="upcoming" type="button" value="Orange Background" />
```

Been trying to figure this out but the color of the **more** `button` still changes even if it's already slided up...

Comment: If wide is synonymous with orange, and not-wide is synonymous with blue, then simply change a css directive to make the color change in synchronism with the width change. Javascript stays the same, but could be tidied. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bnf3c6cf/)

Comment: And change "wide" to "narrow" all through (CSS, HTML, Javascript) because as it stands, 'wide' is narrow and not 'wide' is wide.

Comment: And real soon you will be wanting to change "More" for ""Less. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bnf3c6cf/1/)

Answer (score 1):

add this in your $(document).ready

```
   $('input#upcoming').on('click', function(){

            $('a#toggle').css({'background':'#f4b066'});
             $('#btn-chat').css({'background':'#f4b066'});
        })
```

working example 
http://jsfiddle.net/vo0d9ubj/5/

Answer (score 1):

This should to do it, add this below the changeColor function:

```
function changeOrange(color) {
 if ($('#btn-chat').hasClass('wide'))
     document.getElementById("btn-chat").style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

If the background is already orange, and the more button moves up, should the background change back to blue?

Comment: @Kenny: Your solution doesn't check to see if the more button has been moved up before changing its background color

Answer (score 1):

Check the condition  `$("#blk-collaboration .chatbox").is(':visible')` whether the **More** is toggled or not. Here i'm using the variable `tempBottom` to check the More div

Try this piece of Query

```
var tempBottom=true;

function changeColor(color) {
    document.getElementById("circle").style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
function changeOrange(color) {
    if(tempBottom==true){
    $('.wide').css("background-color", "#f4b066");
    }
}
    document.getElementById("online").onclick = function() { changeColor("#92bf1e"); }
    document.getElementById("offline").onclick = function() { changeColor("#747474"); } 
    document.getElementById("upcoming").onclick = function() { changeOrange("#f4b066"); } 

        $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.chatbox').hide();
        $('#btn-chat').click(function() {
            $("#blk-collaboration .chatbox").slideToggle("slow",function(){
            $("#blk-collaboration #toggle").css("background","transparent");
                if( $("#blk-collaboration .chatbox").is(':visible')){
                    tempBottom=false;}else
                    { tempBottom=true;
                    }
        });
          $(this)//this is a button DOM element. wrapping in jQuery object.
          .toggleClass('wide'); // removing wide class so button became smaller.
        });
    });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nrsantharam/vo0d9ubj/4/)

Answer (score 1):

In your case, here is how to do it...

```
$("#upcoming").on("click", function(){  

    // check if 'More' button's position is in between 100px from the bottom
   if( ($("#toggle").offset().top >= ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() - 100))) {

      // change the color        
      $("center").css("background", "#eebe57");

   }    

});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kmtfgzf9/)
(Scroll to bottom of the Javascript section!)